# RULES(NOEVENPACK) in Enterprise COBOL. Why we need to check if packed-decimal is not in even digits?

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I am reading the following statement and I am not sure why we must have the packed-decimal in odd digits? Is the following statement true, that you can only have odd number of digits in hardware? Can you give me a example to show why it says that?

> RULES(NOEVENPACK) This compiler option will tell you if you
>   accidentally define a Pack Decimal data item within even number of
>   digits. You can only have odd number of digits in hardware. If you
>   have one byte you have one digit , 2 byte you have 3 digit, 3 byte
>   -->5 digit.

Comment: I would guess it is about negative values - you need 4 bit for values from 0 to 9, so you can store 2 digits in one byte. but you need also one bit for the sign, the remaining 3 bits are not enough for 0 ..9

Comment: @nabuchodonossor four bits are used for the sign. Four bits for each digit. Thus, with eight bits to a byte, there are always an odd number of digits.

Comment: The RULES compiler option is for Enterprise COBOL on an IBM Mainframe. I've removed the opencobol tag. Probably the same happens with GnuCOBOL (the new-ish name for OpenCOBOL), GnuCOBOL doesn't have RULES.

Comment: @h-zang: I suggest to mark Bill's answer as "accepted", this should be possible, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

In a packed-decimal field, the right-most half-byte (nybble) is the sign position. Each other half-byte in the field is a digit, 0-9.

This means that the storage occupied by a packed-decimal field represents an odd number of digits. You have no choice over that.

If you define `PACKED-DECIMAL PIC 9(4)` you get

```
?NNNNS
```

Where N is a digit (see, there are four of them) and S is the sign (since the field is defined as unsigned, it will have a sign of F, which is always treated as positive).

What about that ?. It can't not be there. Since it can't not be there, the compiler has to generate code so that it can only contain a zero, which won't affect the value of the field.

If you define `PACKED-DECIMAL PIC 9(5)` you get

```
NNNNNS
```

Five digits, sign, and nothing else for the compiler to worry about. No code generated beyond what is otherwise required for the field.

So your code runs faster.

You may wonder "how much does that matter?". If you consider how many packed-decimal fields you may see in a program, if each of those, every time it was referenced, had code to make the first digit zero, you've got quite a lot of code, for every pass through the program.

On the Mainframe you, generally, pay for resource-usage. If you avoid that in 5,000 programs which are processing 10,000,000 transactions a day, 365 days a year, then it adds up.

Comment: Thank you very much Bill. This is really good explanation and excellent example.